# Bit field memory usage in C

Tags: c, struct, field, bit

Why does it return with 96 and not 64?
If I sum bit of bit field I will get 64.

**Edited:**

*The `var` variable has `0xFFFFFF` and not `0xFFFFFFFF`.* -> The `var` variable has `0x3FFFFFFF00FFFFFF` and not `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct{
    uint32_t a : 24;
    uint32_t b : 20;
    uint32_t c : 10;
    uint32_t d : 6;
    uint32_t e : 4;
}MyType_t;

int main(){
    MyType_t test;
    test.a = -1;
    test.b = -1;
    test.c = -1;
    test.d = -1;
    test.e = -1;

    uint64_t var = *((uint64_t*)&test);

    printf("MyType_t: %d bit\n", sizeof(MyType_t) * 8);//96 bit
    printf("Var: %#llX\n", var);//0x3FFFFFFF00FFFFFF
    return 0;
}
```

This code will be worked correctly:

```
typedef struct{
    uint32_t a : 16;
    uint32_t b : 16;
    uint32_t c : 16;
    uint32_t d : 8;
    uint32_t e : 8;
}MyType_t;
```

Comment: Change `uint32_t` to `uint64_t`, then `sizeof(MyType_t)` will give `8` instead of `12`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, on what basis do you say so?  That is, I don't doubt that what you say is true for some implementations, but I'm pretty sure that nothing in the standard requires it to be true.  In particular, even if the implementation chooses to use units of type `uint32_t` to hold the bits (which is not required), it is implementation-defined whether the bitfields will be split across those storage units.

Comment: @JohnBollinger only because it seemed obvious, having 64 bits in total, and field sizes that break across 32-bit. Although I can see that some implementations might succeed with the posted code, I fail to see how using a 64-bit type might not succeed.

Comment: @WeatherVane because the declared type of a bitfield has no required association with the size of the storage units in which its bits are held.  Just changing the `uint32_t` bitfield declarations to `uint64_t` does not require any difference in the layout or resulting size (e.g. three 32-bit units could still be used).

Comment: @JohnBollinger hmmm yes it does: the declared type must be at least as big as the bitfield to be coded.

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, the declared type of a bitfield must be big enough to accommodate the number of bits, but that type has very little to do with the *representation* of the bitfield, the structure containing it, or, therefore the size of that structure.

Comment: the problem is that the bit fields are defined as 32 bit entities so any field that crosses a 32 bit boundary will be 'pushed' to the next 32 bits in memory.   The result is there are several 'gaps' in the data.   This is also obvious when you try to print out the whole area and only get 64 of the 96 bits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fields a and b cannot possibly fit into a single type of uint32_t:

```
typedef struct{
    uint32_t a : 24;    //first 32 bits
    uint32_t b : 20;    //second 32 bits
    uint32_t c : 10;    //
    uint32_t d : 6;     //third 32 bits
    uint32_t e : 4;     //
}MyType_t;
```

so the size of the struct is three times the size of uint32_t.

---

The behavior of the code `uint64_t var = *((uint64_t*)&test);` is not defined.

Comment: Good illustration of why you should not rely on reinterpretation of a bit-field...

Comment: Whether `a` and `b` can fit into a single `uint32_t` isn't much relevant without reference to a particular implementation, for the standard makes no association whatever between a bitfield's declared type and the size of the addressable storage unit in which it is stored.  Indeed, the standard places few requirements on how bitfields are laid out within the addressible storage units dedicated to holding their bits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah I'm making assumptions about OPs implementation. That part of the standard is very loose.